# Examples of GTK and plplot?

Tags: c, macos, plot, gtk, gnome

I am trying to embed a plplot graphics inside a gtk window at OSX. I used plplotcanvas but so far i have no success at all. At the wiki there is one example (http://archive.tcltk.co.kr/doc/plplot-html-5.9.4/gui.html) but i can find nothing else. The version i am using is 5.10.0.

Anyone knows how to do it or any advise?. At the examples on the wiki the compiler can not find plplotcanvas.h after change the libraries the compiler says the same for every function:

```
plem.c:62:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'plplot_canvas_plwid' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        plplot_canvas_plwid(canvas,2);
```

It is the same with every function of plplotcanvas. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Either you got a version mismatch of libs and API you use, a typo, or you simply forgot to include appropriate headers.

---

For a more detailed diagnosis you need to post some (relevant) code chunks.

---

[There are plenty of examples for plplot usage, each screenshot links to a full code example](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php)

Comment: My cose chunk ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477960/error-after-compile-plplot-embedded-with-gtk i was searching i can not find too many examples using plplot 5.10... I keep searching and trying :3

Comment: The above post contains a link to a page with at least 20 examples for plplot.

Comment: I sorry i did not read at all "the examples show pngcairo" then i will try to use plplot-cairo-gtk. Thanks drahnr :)

Comment: Well you know that plplot has multiple backends, right?

Comment: Yep. I am a little bit newbie at this ( i am retaking code at C/C++ seriously after years of inactivity ). And it is a little bit strange, sometimes i am angry because nothing seems to work, then everything works and so on… also i am retaking electronics (the platform use code+sensors+circuits) and mechanics so i am learning a lot ( i love it ) but sometimes i feel i am to dumb or too slow… but i keep working :)